# Inserir o texto em suas devidas células - Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, split

Olá, amigos

[image]

Estou desenvolvendo o código para que possa limpar e organizar os dados (conforme apresentado acima) e umas das melhores formas foi inserir os dados dentro de um arquivo **CSV** para que posteriormente pudesse retorna-lo em formato de planilha, dessa forma apliquei o seguinte código:

```
import csv

with open('/content/Pasta2.csv', 'w') as out_file:
      writer = csv.writer(out_file, delimiter=',',lineterminator='\n')
      writer.writerow(('URL','Documento', 'Código CVM', 'Data de Referência', 'Status'))
      writer.writerow([linha_1])

teste_02 = pd.read_csv('/content/Pasta2.csv')

teste_02
```

**Porém,** o retorno que eu tenho é o apresentado na imagem a baixo, o código pega simplesmente o texto que está dentro do "linha_1' e não faz a divisão nas células, gostaria de saber qual código posso implementar para resolver esse problema, conseguem me ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Resultado Esperado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Código que deu certo:

```
import csv

with open('/content/Pasta2.csv', 'w') as out_file:
      
      writer = csv.writer(out_file, delimiter=',',lineterminator='')
      writer.writerow(('URL','Documento', 'Código CVM', 'Data de Referência', 'Status'))
      writer.writerow(linha_1.replace('"','').split(','))

teste_02 = pd.read_csv('/content/Pasta2.csv')

teste_02
```

Fiz algumas alterações e o resultado deu certo, foi realizado a distribuição correta nas linhas e também as quebras de linha.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que você está escrevendo a linha inteira na primeira célula, tenta trocar a linha 6 por:

```
writer.writerow(*[linha_1])
```

Comment: olá, Onilol

Tentei da forma que você falou, mas não deu certo, o mais próximo que eu consegui chegar foi dessa forma, ele separou nas colunas, mas não realiza a quebra das linhas:
'''
import csv

with open('/content/Pasta2.csv', 'w') as out_file:
      
      writer = csv.writer(out_file, delimiter=',',lineterminator='\n')
      writer.writerow(('URL','Documento', 'Código CVM', 'Data de Referência', 'Status'))
      writer.writerow(linha_1.replace('"','').split(' '))

teste_02 = pd.read_csv('/content/Pasta2.csv')

teste_02

Comment: Hmmm, da uma olhada na documentacao do modulo `csv` entao, lembro que tem uma forma de mapear os cabeçalhos e ja printa tudo bonitinho.

Comment: Opa, consegui! Vou postar a resposta abaixo, obrigado pela ajuda, Onilol.